# SOLVED - Vue JS Google Map markers from JSON file. Unexpected token }in JSON at position 139

Tags: json, google-maps, vue.js, google-maps-markers

I'm using Vue JS and I'm trying to create markers for a Google map from JSON file.
This is the whole error message:
"Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 139
    at JSON.parse ()
    at Object.module.exports (E:\just\path\project\node_modules\json-loader\index.js:4:49)"
It says that the problem is at index.js at position 4:49 but I don't know what should be wrong. I have never edited this file.

Here is the script part of a file map.vue:

```
    <script>

import { stanice } from '../json/data.json'

export default{
  name: "Map",
  data () {
    return {
      center: { lat: 50.425, lng: 14.907 },
      infoContent: '',
      infoWindowPos: null,
      infoWinOpen: false,
      currentMidx: null,
      infoOptions: {
          pixelOffset: {
          width: 0,
          height: -35
          }
        },
     };
  },
  computed: {
    markers() {
      return stanice.map(({ location: { lat, lng }, name }) => ({
        position: {
          lat,
          lng
        },
        name
      }));
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getPosition: function(marker) {
      return {
        lat: parseFloat(marker.position.lat),
        lng: parseFloat(marker.position.lng)
      }
    },
    toggleInfoWindow: function(marker, index) {
      this.infoWindowPos = this.getPosition(marker);
      this.infoContent = marker.text;

      if (this.currentMidx == index) {
        this.infoWinOpen = !this.infoWinOpen;
      }
      else{
        this.infoWinOpen = true;
        this.currentMidx = index;
      }
    }
  }
};

</script>
```

This is data.json file:

```
{
  "stanice": [
    {
      "name": "Meteostanice 1",
      "location": {
        "lat": 50.43,
        "lng": 14.91
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Meteostanice 2",
      "location": {
        "lat": 50.43,
        "lng": 14.915
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Meteostanice 3",
      "location": {
        "lat": 50.43,
        "lng": 14.92
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is that index.js file located in json-loader folder:

```
module.exports = function (source) {
  if (this.cacheable) this.cacheable();

  var value = typeof source === "string" ? JSON.parse(source) : source;

  value = JSON.stringify(value)
    .replace(/\u2028/g, '\\u2028')
    .replace(/\u2029/g, '\\u2029');

  return `module.exports = ${value}`;
}
```

Some stuff is in my native language so I hope it's not a problem ;)

Thanks everyone for help !

Comment: Update your title don't paste random syntax errors. You can search for a json validator tool. But I reckon it's to do with trailing commas in your json file e.g. `"location": {
        "lat": 50.43,
        "lon": 14.92
      }, remove the `,` after `}`

Comment: Got it, these commas were the problem, thanks @MonteCristo